# Obter o valor da variavél url para iframe

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Eu gostaria de ajuda veja o exemplo:

```
http://www.site.com/pagina.php?url=http://www.valordavariavel.com
```

No meu php: pagina.php eu tenho o iframe:

```
<iframe src="" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Agora como faço para obter o valor da variável `url` para o iframe `src=""`

o resultado que eu gostaria de obter é:

```
<iframe src="http://www.valordavariavel.com" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Já tentei:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Mas não deu certo, agradeço desde já pela atenção obrigado!

Comment: "Não deu certo" é muito vago. Como ficou o source da página com a sua tentativa? Você fez `$url = $_GET['url'];` antes dessa linha? Num servidor bem configurado, o `$_GET` é fundamental.

Comment: ´não coloquei o get como faz você poderia escrever o codigo aqui pra mim?

Comment: É exatamente o que está escrito no comentário anterior. Na parte PHP do seu código você tem que por a linha mencionada, ou usar o `$_GET['url']` no `echo`

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar o método `GET`:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

E no `iframe` colocar:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```